# Is it possible to declare a does not contain partial match with a With statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I'm trying to attach a simple macro to a command button that will manipulate the report filter on a pivot table.  I'm still quite new to VBA so I manually filtered the pivot table and recorded the macro.

A Sample of the recorded macro;

```
Sub Macro1()

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Attribute1Value"). _
    CurrentPage = "(All)"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Attribute1Value")
    .PivotItems("blank - no bc category value").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("boys | boys/accessories").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("boys | boys/accessories | girls | girls/accessories").Visible _
    = False
    .PivotItems("boys | boys/baby-boy").Visible = False
```

This goes on and on for the thousands of different store category values I have.

So here's the code I've put together;

```
Private Sub testbutton1_Click()

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Attribute1Value"). _
    CurrentPage = "(All)"

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Attribute1Value")
    .PivotItems("beauty").Visible = False



End With

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Attribute1Value"). _
    EnableMultiplePageItems = True


End Sub
```

It works, but only with exact matches and at the moment it does the opposite of what I need it to do (only displays Inventory Numbers which don't have the value "Beauty" as it's store category, I need it to display everything that contains "Beauty" or "Beaut" etc. as a lot of the store category values are dual-categorised e.g. " Beauty | Womens/Accessories" ).  Changing it to ("beauty").Visible = True does nothing.

Any and all advice will be hugely appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Comment: sounds maybe you can use Like with wildcards or Instr

Comment: I've seen a few tutorials which suggest using Like but I'm not too sure of how to incorporate it with a With statement unfortunately

Comment: Can you use like to set it in a variable and then use With variable ? Error handle appropriately.

Comment: Could you provide a small example of how to implement this?  I'm still quite the amateur when it comes to VBA at the moment